# What happens when I use [::-1] with a variable?

Tags: python, variables, definition

So I have this code:

```
t=int(input())
while t:
 s=int(input())
 n=bin(s)
 n=n[2:][::-1]
 if n.count('1')==1:
  pos=n.find('1')+1
  print(pos)
else:
  print('-1')
t-=1
```

I would like to know exactly what's going on in this line:

```
 n=n[2:][::-1]
```

What does [::-1] means?

Comment: Short answer: It's the canonical reversing slice; it returns a shallow copy of the input in reverse order.

Comment: The [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/) is really good. Please try to read it a little more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It takes the reverse of binary value of n excluding "0b" values in the beginning. For example if you enter 6 for value of n. The binary value would be 0b110 and reverse value excluding 0b would be 011.